# Вывести из записи только 150 символов

Tags: php

Есть запись в базе, в ней содержится много символов.
Я хочу вывести на страницу только 150 символов, а если в записи больше чем 150 символов, то чтобы добавляло **...** к этим 150-ти выводимым символам.

Делаю так:

```
$strl = 150;
$xt=strlen($workID0['date']);
$tx=substr($workID0['date'],0,$strl);
$tx=nl2br($tx);
if($xt>$strl){$txx="......";} else {$txx="";}

echo ''.$tx.$txx.'';
```

Получается все как надо. Но некоторые записи обрезает так, что в конце обрезанного слова получается каракозябра в виде вопроса.

Как  это поправить? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$strl = 150;
$xt=iconv_strlen($workID0['date'], 'UTF-8');
$tx=iconv_substr($workID0['date'], 0, $strl, 'UTF-8');
$tx=nl2br($tx);
if($xt>$strl){$txx="......";} else {$txx="";}

echo ''.$tx.$txx.'';
```

если кодировка отличается от UTF-8, замените на Вашу.

Comment: так вообще не обрезает текст

Comment: Значит, у Вас что-то не так. Кодировка какая?

Comment: соединение с базой UTF-8

Comment: Кодировка скрипта должна тоже быть в UTF-8. Надо дебажить на Вашем окружении. В нормально настроеном РНР, когда на вход подана строка utf-8, код работает как должен. Попробуйте с какой-нибудь рандомной строкой

Answer (score 3):

Потому что неправильно узнал длину строки.
Используй **mb_**strlen и **mb_**substr

mb_ для многобайтных кодировок. например utf-8

Comment: Можно пример какой-нибудь?

Comment: $stroka = mb_substr($drugaya_stroka,0,500)

Comment: вообще в таком случае не обрезает

Comment: так получается что запись не обрезается, и **...** добавляется в том случае когда запись короче 150-т символов. все наоборот

Comment: изменил кодировку на `$xt=iconv_strlen($workID0['date'], 'cp1251');
$tx=iconv_substr($workID0['date'], 0, $strl, 'cp1251');` получается теперь обрезает текст, но каракозябра присутствует